# How to detect that all the child processes launched in a script ended?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I wanted to launch several commands in parallel by using a `for` loop, each command can take more or less time, and I want to call another command at the end of the script. Here is a minimal example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function test {
    length=$1
    sleep $length

    echo "$length"
    echo "-----"
}

# http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop-array/    
array=( 5 1 3 )

for time in "${array[@]}"
do
    test $time &
done
```

Here is the result:

```bash
$ bash ~/test.sh && echo "OK"
OK
$ 1
-----
3
-----
5
-----
```

As you can see, `OK` is displayed before the script ended, this is logical since I called `test` in background with `&`. I can't add a test on the last `test` call since it can end before the other calls. I would like that the script exit only once all the `test` instances called in background are ended.

Here is what the result I'm trying to obtain:

```bash
$ bash ~/test.sh && echo "OK"
1
-----
3
-----
5
-----
OK
$
```

How can I get this output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to [wait](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-wait) after the `for` loop, so all currently active child processes are waited for:

```
for time in "${array[@]}"
do
    test "$time" &
done

wait
```